# How does the extensible "SomeException" fit in with the Haskell standards?

Tags: exception, haskell, standards

In section 7.3 of the Haskell 2010 standard I read the following:

> The I/O monad includes a simple exception handling system. Any I/O
>   operation may raise an exception instead of returning a result.
>
> Exceptions in the I/O monad are represented by values of type IOError.
>   This is an abstract type: its constructors are hidden from the user.
>   The IO library defines functions that construct and examine IOError
>   values. The only Prelude function that creates an IOError value is
>   userError. User error values include a string describing the error.

The text of the Haskell 98 standard is almost identical.

In practice however I often see catch construction with SomeException from Control.Exception.Base:

> The SomeException type is the root of the exception type hierarchy.
>   When an exception of type e is thrown, behind the scenes it is
>   encapsulated in a SomeException.

A small experiment with GHC shows that also an IOException is encapsulated in a SomeException.

```
import GHC.IO(failIO)
import Control.Exception(catch, SomeException(..))

main :: IO ()
main = (x >>= print) `catchAll` \e -> print ("caught: " ++ show e)

x :: IO Int
x = failIO "Failed to get x!"

catchAll :: IO a -> (SomeException -> IO a) -> IO a
catchAll = catch
```

Running above program gives us:

```
caught: user error (Failed to get x!)
```

How does this fit in with the standard? Is it a GHC specific extension of the Haskell standard?

Comment: I believe it's an extension. If you stick to the Report exceptions, only, everything should behave according to the report. Once you use GHC-specific extensions, their semantics is no longer mandated by the Report.

Answer (score 3):

GHC still has all the machinery described in the report for `IOError`, etc.

However, in practice that was found to be very limiting, as people needed to introduce new exception types for imprecise and later asynchronous exceptions. Thus a new module was born to manage all these types uniformly. However, this module then had the problem that while it extended the universe of exceptions available, it did so in a fixed way. Thus was born the desire for an *Extensible* mechanism for extensions. The design, motivations, and implementation were provided in a 2006 paper by Simon Marlow (http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/ext-exceptions.pdf).

That brings us to the `Control.Exception` modules we know and love today.

As the paper describes, the library is basically implemented in userland, with only the necessity of a few language-level constructs such as existentials and `Typeable`.